# Simple ordinary differential equation in r squared

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this simple looking 1D problem, but I can't seem to express $r(t)$ explicitely

$$
\ddot{r}r^2-a=0
$$

where a is $a$ constant

(it originates from $F=G\frac{M_1M_2}{r^2}=M_1\ddot{r} $, the force between two pointmasses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
2\dot{r}\ddot{r} = {a \over r^{2}}\,2\dot{r}\quad\imp\quad
\totald{\dot{r}^{2}}{t} = -2a\,\totald{}{t}\pars{1 \over r}\quad\imp\quad
\totald{}{t}\pars{\dot{r}^{2} + {2a \over r}} = 0 
\end{align}
Then, $\dot{r}^{2} + 2a/r = 2a/r_{0}$ $\pars{~\mbox{assuming}\ a > 0~}$  and
$0 \leq r_{0} \leq r, \forall r$
\begin{align}
t + \overbrace{C}^{\mbox{constant}}
&=\int{\dd r \over \root{2a/r_{0} - 2a/r}}
=\root{r_{0} \over 2a}\int{\root{r}\,\dd r \over \root{r - r_{0}}} 
\\[3mm]&
=\root{r_{0} \over 2a}\
\overbrace{\int{\root{r_{0} + z^{2}}\pars{2z\,\dd z} \over z}}
^{r\ \equiv\ r_{0} + z^{2}}
=\root{2r_{0} \over a}\int\root{r_{0} + z^{2}}\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&=\root{2r_{0} \over a}\
\overbrace{\int\root{r_{0}}\sec\pars{\theta}\,\root{r_{0}}\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}
\,\dd\theta}
^{z\ \equiv\ \root{r_{0}}\tan\pars{\theta}}
\\[3mm]&=r_{0}\root{2r_{0} \over a}
\int\sec^{3}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\end{align}
Could you continue from here ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin by dividing by $r^2$, then multiply by $\dot r$. You can now integrate the equation once to get a first order equation. In physical terms, this really boils down to the conservation of energy.